Why is there a difference in touch sensitivity when using batteries and SMPS?
We are developing capacitive touch. We are reviewing PIC and Renesas MCU.
However, I discovered an interesting phenomenon.
When I set the touch sensitivity in battery condition and connected it to SMPS, I found that the touch sensitivity changed drastically.
Why does touch sensitivity differ depending on the power environment?

Is it because of SMPS noise?

Could it be the GND difference?
So what is the difference between battery GND and SMPS battery GND?



Sounds noise and/or leakage related. Please post a schematic. What power supply are you using? What’s your grounding situation?

It is a common problem with ac-dc adapters and common-mode noise present on the dc output. You can check this article and maybe find interesting links in this one.

A capacitive earth connection via Y capacitor inside the SMPS can increase the sensitivity a lot. Is this the case here or is the sensitivity lower with connected SMPS? Is there a difference if you swap L and N of the mains?

It is very likely due to SMPS noise. The noise "lands" on the DC output because of EMI filtering inside the SMPS (that removes high-frequency switching noise from the DC output). The filter removes the HF noise to enable the SMPS to pass EMC regulations.
But, in doing so, it transfers a small/moderate amount of common-mode AC (from the power line) onto the DC output and, it's this common-mode voltage that is the likely culprit in reducing the touch sensitivity when AC powered.
You can sometimes feel a small tingle when you touch the DC output of of an SMPS and, this is the culprit.
If you used an SMPS that uses a three-pronged-power-plug (where the middle prong is proper "earth") you probably won't have any difference in sensitivity but, I suspect that your SMPS has a two-prong-power-plug thus, you get a moderate amount of common-mode AC on the DC output that "fogs" the sensitivity of the capacitive touch circuit.
